# how to disable past and today dates on react-bootstrap-date-picker node module for react js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I used react-bootstrap-date-picker node module for datepicker. Now I have a problem to disable past date and today date in my datepicker. Please help me.
Thanks

```
var DatePicker = require("react-bootstrap-date-picker");

<DatePicker id="example-datepicker" value={this.state.strDiscountEndDate} onChange={this.changeExpiredDate.bind(this)} startDate={'today'}  required />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading over to their [docs](https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker#api-reference) their is an option `minDate` to set the lowest allowable date value. Set that value to tomorrow's date ISO string:

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);  // tomorrow
const minDateValue = date.toISOString();  // convert to ISO string
<DatePicker
  minDate={minDateValue} />
```

Comment: I used like this "<DatePicker id="example-datepicker"  minDate={new Date().toISOString()} />".It have still error.@Dane

Comment: Ok. It's a bug they've fixed, but not yet shipped to npm. See https://github.com/pushtell/react-bootstrap-date-picker/issues/139